# Way to unfold/expand a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm looking for a way to easily expand a table as shown in the screenshot below [image]. I have to expand tables in up to ~100 such files at a time, so it'd be great if there's a way to automate that or have a macro to do it quickly.

Thank you in advanced for your answers/suggestions!

Comment: There are many examples on how to do this with vba on this site alone.  what have you tried/found?

Comment: What is the source of your top table?

Comment: Probably the easiest is to unmerge the cells then fill the empty with values from above.  Search `Fill empty cells with values from above` and you will find code that will do this.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks, Scott. I'm a beginner user in Excel. If there's a term that describes what I'm trying to accomplish (I'm not even sure if 'unfolding' is the right term), that would help me search for more resources around.

Comment: I told you what to look for.  `Unmerge` and `Fill empty cells with values from above`

Comment: Please check your source - I know that in SAP's BEx you can uncheck 'suppress repeated values' to have the output as you want.